# Maximizing the number of parallel lines, can you beat the regular $n$-gon?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

Given $n$ points in the plane, with no 3 on a line, there are $n(n-1)/2$ lines that pass through exactly 2 of them. We partition these $n(n-1)/2$ lines in equivalence classes where lines are equivalent if they are parallel.

**What is the lowest number of equalence classes we can get?**

- Putting the $n$ points on the corners of a regular $n$-gon we get $n$ equivalence classes.
- The minimum can not be less than $n-1$ since no two of the $n-1$ lines through a given point are parallel to each other.

This leaves us with only two possibilities for the answer, and based on playing around a bit in GeoGebra the answer is $n$ rather than $n-1$. In other words: it seems impossible to beat the regular $n$-gon.

This makes sense intuitively: things that minimize or maximize some quantity are often highly symmetrical and you can't beat the regular $n$-gon when it comes to symmetry.

But on the other hand: this question can be reformulated in terms of abstract projective geometry as follows, and there the notion of 'regular' does not make a whole lot of sense:

> In a projective plane, let a line $l$ and $n$ points not on $l$ be given such that no three points lie on the same line. Each two of the $n$ points define a a unique line through them that in turn intersects $l$. Obviously the maximum number of such intersections is $n(n-1)/2$ but what is the minimum and how to attain it?

In this formulation it is not even clear at first sight that the answer must be $\geq n-1$ (although on second sight it is, since two lines that share two points must be equal) so I don't think this more general formulation is very useful, but maybe it is? It would indeed be interesting to know if the answer would be different for projective planes over finite fields from what it is in the original formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROOF (For the original formulation)

Form the convex hull of the points and let $u,v,w$ be three successive points on this hull. Then consider the $n-1$ lines through $v$ and the line $uw$.

Any point other than $v$ on a line through $v$ parallel to $uw$ would be outside the convex hull and so we have found $n$ non-parallel lines as required.

Comment: Aaah this is great! It is also very much an argument in the standard Euclidean plane, which raises the question if in finite projective planes a counterexample might be possible or, perhaps even better, a way to translate the 'essence' of being a convex hull to that setting that enables us to use (a translated version of) this proof. Both would be extremely interesting, I will think about that some more

Comment: Yes, likewise! Nice question.

Answer (score 1):

FINITE PROJECTIVE PLANES (Preliminary thoughts - too long for comments)

Your idea seems very interesting. It certainly has different results from the Euclidean case. For example, the bound of $n-1$ can (at least sometimes) be attained.

Consider a projective plane of order $2$. (There is only one but we don't need to know that.)

Take any line $l$. This has three points.

Consider the set $S$ of four points not on $l$.

If any three points of $S$ were on a line then this line would intersect $l$ and therefore would have more than three points, which is impossible.

The lines joining pairs of points of $S$ then intersect $l$ at only three points.

MAXIMISING $n$

In the comments you propose that

*the maximal number of points that can simultaneously satisfy the two conditions (no 3 on a line and no one of them on a special, pre-specified line) is  1 more than the number of points on a line (so q+2 for order q planes)*

If we ignore the pre-specified line, then a relevant result is stated here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278762/largest-number-of-points-one-can-pick-in-finite-projective-space-without-getting

In $PG(2,q)$ the maximum is $q+1$ for odd $q$ but $q+2$ for even $q$.

Comment: Yes I had also thought of this example in the mean time. In general it seems at first glance that you can make arbitrarily large counterexamples over finite projective planes by taking $n$ to be much bigger than the number of points on a line. But from the argument in my original post we already know that we cannot do that. Apparently this shows that the number of points that can simultaneously satisfy the two conditions (no 3 on a line and no one of them on a special, pre-specified line) is maximal 1 more than the number of points on a line (so $q + 2$ for order $q$ planes).

Comment: In the order 2 case the two conditions form the previous comment are equivalent, but this is not the case in general (I think). I wonder what would break down first if you try to put q + 3 points

Comment: I've added a reference from mathoverflow.

Comment: Hey this very interesting. I was just getting the impression that it was impossible to pick 5 points in general position $PG(2, 3)$, but that is indeed true, then? This odd even thing is quite fascinating!